# Bad Code given by Developer for Magento Theme

Tags: php, html, magento

I was given this code by the developer of the magento theme I am using but get an error after placing in the file where I was told to. Can someone please tell me what could be wrong with this code?

```
<div class="short-description clear">
<div class="std"><?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, nl2br($_product->getShortDescription();, 'short_description') ?></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's an extra `;` after `$_product->getShortDescription()` that doesn't belong there. Also there should be another closing bracket after `'short_description')`. Change the PHP line to:

```
<?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, nl2br($_product->getShortDescription(), 'short_description')); ?>
```

Comment: Still getting "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ';'" after that change

Comment: Apologies I just spotted another mistake, which was a missing closing bracket. I have updated my answer with the new code solution.

Comment: Found a solution! A set of () was not closed:
"($_product, nl2br($_product->getShortDescription())"

Also used the ; move/change you mentioned!